# android studio gives an error when using Data Binding with a class in another module, but compiles fine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, kotlin-multiplatform

When using data binding in a layout, and one of the variables is in my kotlin multiplatform shared module, I get an error when trying to access the variable in the code.

The project builds just fine, but there are errors in almost every file.

I checked that the paths are all in lowercase, and the class in uppercase, but it still gives me this error:

`Cannot access class 'com.example.shared.viewmodels.MyViewModel'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

It happens when I use it like `binding.viewModel = myViewModel`

`.viewModel` is underlines with an error